# How can I write this Excel IF statement?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Trying to write an if statement:

```
if (A1*.02) < 500, enter calculated total, if > 500 enter 500
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

You can go a bit simpler than an if statement here:

```
=MIN(A1*0.02,500)
```

This does the same thing as suggested by the other posters, but is more concise. Takes the lesser value of either A1*0.02 or 500.

Comment: A little less *clear* but a great approach.

Comment: I'll concede that 'clear' may be a bit subjective.

Answer (score 1):

Excel's IF Formula is:

```
=If(Test,ValueifTru,ValueifFalse)
```

You can wrap conditions in between the commas, or add more condtions.

```
=IF(A2*0.02 <500,A2*0.02,500)
```

Would work, but for added readibility you could also:

```
=IF((A2*0.02) <500,A2*0.02,500)
```

Or

```
=IF(((A2*0.02) <500),(A2*0.02),500)
```

Comment: How is your first "added readability" option any differnt than mine? +1 for explaining the `IF` statement syntax...

Comment: @ARich Long answers that provide some explanation and context are better than just giving a one-line answer. We should always explain why what we are recommending is a valid solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
If((A1*0.02)<500,A1*0.02,500)
```